# Latest Data Based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data something like below

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+
|      Createdon      | Purchasing_Order_Number | Item_Number | Net_Price |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| Nov 22 2017  4:31PM | 18M-101499              |           1 | 369.00    |
| Nov 22 2017  4:31PM | 18M-101499              |           2 | 95.00     |
| Nov 22 2017  4:31PM | 18M-101499              |           3 | 175.00    |
| Nov 22 2017  4:31PM | 18M-101499              |           4 | 10.00     |
| Nov 22 2017  4:31PM | 18M-101499              |           5 | 220.00    |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           1 | 450.00    |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           2 | 95.00     |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           3 | 175.00    |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           4 | 10.00     |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           5 | 220.00    |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Need only latest values. Output should be like below.

```
|      Createdon      | Purchasing_Order_Number | Item_Number | Net_Price |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           1 |    450.00 |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           2 |     95.00 |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           3 |    175.00 |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           4 |     10.00 |
| Nov 30 2017  2:45PM | 18M-101499              |           5 |    220.00 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+

select max(Createdon), Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, Net_Price 
from [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure]
where IsDeleted = 0 
group by Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, Net_Price
order by Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number
```

But I am getting different values.

Please help me with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER()` with a partition on the item number to identify the latest records:

```
SELECT
    Createdon, Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, Net_Price
FROM
(
    SELECT Createdon, Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, Net_Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number
                           ORDER BY Createdon DESC) rn
    FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure]
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

For bonus points, or if you cannot use an analytic function for some reason, the problem with your current approach is that you only have a single level `GROUP BY` query.  This can only find the latest date per item, but not the entire record.  If you want to continue with your current approach then you can join to the query you have in mind, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, MAX(Createdon) AS max_created
    FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure]
    GROUP BY Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number
) t2
    ON t1.Purchasing_Order_Number = t2.Purchasing_Order_Number AND
       t1.Item_Number = t2.Item_Number AND
       t1.Createdon = t2.max_created;
```

Both of these approaches actually have a limitation, namely that should there be an exact tie for the latest record, for a given item number, only one record would be identified.  The join approach I gave does not really have a workaround for this, but my first query does.  We can replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` in this case, and then all ties for the latest record, per item, would be returned.

Comment: I am not getting exact outputs.

Comment: @user2293950 I may have botched my initial answer.  I ignored the `Purchasing_Order_Number` column as being just metadata, when in fact maybe it should be part of the partition/grouping.  Try my update answers.

Comment: SELECT t1.Purchasing_Order_Number,t1.Item_Number,t1.Createdon,t1.net_price
FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, MAX(Createdon) as max_created
    FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure] where isdeleted=0 --and Purchasing_Order_Number='18M-101499'
    GROUP BY Purchasing_Order_Number,Item_Number
) t2
    ON t1.Purchasing_Order_Number = t2.Purchasing_Order_Number AND
       t1.Item_Number = t2.Item_Number AND
       t1.Createdon = t2.max_created;

First query gives me 50211 records.both queries it gives 50716 records.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to correct your query as follow

just added  `max()` aggregation to your  `Net_Price`

```
Select Max(Createdon),Purchasing_Order_Number,Item_Number,MAX(Net_Price)
from [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure] Where IsDeleted=0 
group by Purchasing_Order_Number,Item_Number
Order by Purchasing_Order_Number,Item_Number
```

Other way is use of window function with `row_number ()` function

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number order by Createdon desc) rn 
           FROM [dbo].[TEPurchase_Item_Structure]  Where IsDeleted=0 
) 
select * from cte where rn =1
```

Comment: Sometimes price will get decreased also. I need to get lates records based on date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Createdon, Purchasing_Order_Number, Item_Number, Net_Price from
(select Createdon,
       Purchasing_Order_Number,
       Item_Number,
       Net_Price
       rank() over (partition by Item_Number order by Createdon) as RN
from TABLE_NAME) as a
where RN = 1
```